# Have Colab reload a recently changed module on Drive

Tags: google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I'd like to use Google Colab as a front-end to repeatedly run code that I am developing in a .py file on my Google Drive. Specifically, I want to edit that file with e.g. vim, and have the Colab Notebook repeatedly reload my changes.

Synchronizing the file with my Drive is easy enough, as is mounting that drive and importing the module *once*. However, reloading the module is not.

Using either `%autoreload 2` or `module = importlib.reload(module))`,
the notebook seems to *eventually* react to the changed file, but very slowly and unpredictably so. Remounting the Drive appears to have no effect. Doing a "factory reset" of the notebook does seem to work, but this is unacceptably slow because I must then input a new authorization code each time to a dialogue box.

Is there any way to achieve the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 4):

I was able to do this with `importlib`

```py
import some_module

import importlib
importlib.reload(some_module)
```

Comment: This answer failed for me, because, no matter what argument I gave to reload, the system said that that wasn't a module. Perhaps I should try asking the colab .py file for the names of modules it has loaded.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem. 
I could (appartently) solve by

- Deleting the `__pycache__` folder
- Terminating the current session (from the menu bar `Runtime > Manage Session > TERMINATE`)
- Restarting runtime (from menu `Runtime > Restart runtime`)

Then reload the module with `importlib.reload(module)`.

Hope it helps!

---

**EDIT** It seems to work also by simply restarting the runtime, with `Runtime > Restart runtime`

Comment: I needed to do `Runtime > Factory reset runtime`

Comment: Is there anyway to not reset the runtime and reimport a module from an edited file?. because I don't want to lose my variables and stuff